# Dealing with "Warning: assignment to free variable" when certain libraries can be missing by design

Tags: byte-compilation, package-development, warning, lexical-scoping

Byte compilation of my mode:

```
(defun dict-setup-expansions ()
  "Add `dict-mode' specific expansions."
  (set (make-local-variable 'er/try-expand-list) (list #'dict-mark-article)))
```

gives warning:

```
Warning: assignment to free variable `er/try-expand-list'
```

This is normal situation because `er/try-expand-list` is defined in external library `expand-region`.

My mode register extension to `expand-region` library but it is ok to run my mode without `expand-region` mode.

I think that proper way to deal with warning is to add declaration:

```
(defvar er/try-expand-list)
```

`defvar` docs say:

```
The `defvar' form also declares the variable as "special",
so that it is always dynamically bound even if `lexical-binding' is t.
```

I use `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-`. Does that mean that without `defvar` variable `er/try-expand-list` be in lexical scope and I have real bug?

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't quote the symbol in the `(defvar er/try-expand-list)`.

Comment: @JeanPierre Fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `set` and `setq` do not declare lexical variables.  Only `let` does.  Had you used `let` here you'd have a bug, but this is fine.  The warning exists mostly to catch typos when using dynamic variables.

To make the warning go away use `defvar` as in your question, but do **not** quote the symbol.

Comment: Is wrapping into `eval-when-compile` redundant to just `defvar`? I see no warning without `eval-when-compile`. Seems that `eval-when-compile` is necessary if use active code, like `(require ...)`...

Comment: Wrapping defvar would be redundant.